# AWS S3 copy object from one bucket to another with different credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to copy object from one bucket to another with different credentials using php?
Because source bucket's credentials are different from target bucket.
One thing I can do is getObject() and save it then putObject().
Is there any straightforward way for this?

Comment: Do you use AWS SDK for PHP?

Comment: If you can't manage IAM roles and bucket policies your approach is the only way to go.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

Comment: @oleskii-donoha Yes, I'm using AWS SDK

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can create two S3-Clients with the different credentials and then use one do download the object and the other to upload the data. This has the drawback, that all data will be downloaded to your machine and the uploaded again, which could potentially use a lot of bandwidth. Also storing that data in memory might become a problem if you're dealing with large objects.

If you can control the **destination** bucket and the role/user in the **source** account there are better options. In this case you can set a bucket policy on the destination bucket to allow the user in the source account to use PutObject + CopyObject on the bucket. You'll then need to add these permissions to your user in the source account as well. Afterwards you can use the [CopyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) API-call to directly copy the objects from the source to the destination bucket without downloading them first. I'd recommend to include the ACL `BucketOwnerFullControl` in the CopyObject call, otherwise you may not have access to the object in the destination account.

Comment: What if I do something like this?

`$s3 = new S3Client(CREDENTIALS_1);
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
   'Bucket' => $sourceBucket,
    'Key'    => $sourceFilename,
));`

`$s3 = new S3Client(CREDENTIALS_2);
$s3->putObject(array(
   'Bucket' => $targetBucket,
   'Key'    => $targetFilename,
   'Body'   => $result['Body']
));`

Comment: I know this coding has a drawback but there's no possibility to change bucket policies.

Comment: That seems roughly equivalent to my first suggestion with the associated drawbacks (I don't speak [tag:php]), so it can work.